# NetBeans git subfolders as branch

Tags: php, git, netbeans, bitbucket

I have project in **NetBeans** as this:

[image: project]

I created GIT repository of **test** project as *master* branch.

### Question:

How can I have **each subfolder as branch** of project test ?

*Note: I am using GIT in NetBeans and http://bitbucket.org as remote GIT.*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Git philosophy, the concept of branch isn't linked to the notion of folder (like it is in SVN).

When you checkout on a specific branch in a Git repository, you are not moving into another directory. You stay where you were, then Git updates the files in the directory so as to reflects the files of the new branch.

So to obtain the arborescence you want, it implies to clone the project several times.

Comment: maybe for this type of project there is SVN a better solution

Comment: Above all, the main question is why he needs several directories at the same time.